# jQuery UI Sortable Multiple element target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 list element

```
<div id="list-one">
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <li data-order="1">item 1</li>
    <li data-order="2">item 2</li>
    <li data-order="3">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="list-two">
  <ul class="ul-two">
    <li data-order="1">item 4</li>
    <li data-order="2">item 5</li>
    <li data-order="3">item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can `ul-two` list element order follow `ul-one` order when I sort `ul-one` using jQuery Sortable ?

I want get the result like

```
<div id="list-one">
  <ul class="ul-one">
    <li data-order="2">item 2</li>
    <li data-order="1">item 1</li>
    <li data-order="3">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="list-two">
  <ul class="ul-two">
    <li data-order="2">item 5</li>
    <li data-order="1">item 4</li>
    <li data-order="3">item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

just drag ul-one element

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you show how you want result look like?

Comment: I have edited description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstand the question.

This is a working solution. I added `id` tag to easy call

http://jsfiddle.net/39ZvN/1141/

Comment: Thanks but I don't want move to another ul, see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="list-one">
  <ul class="sort ul-one">
    <li data-order="1">item 1</li>
    <li data-order="2">item 2</li>
    <li data-order="3">item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br />
<div id="list-two">
  <ul class="sort ul-two">
    <li data-order="1">item 4</li>
    <li data-order="2">item 5</li>
    <li data-order="3">item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>


$( '.sort li' ).each(function() {
      var position = $(this).data('order');
      $(this).siblings().eq(position+1).after(this);
});
```